# Penney's game with biased coins

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I need the victory matrix of Penney's game with general probability p. For example I need to know which is the probability that HHH wins against TTH if the probability to toss T is p, and the probability to toss H is 1-p. I managed to find only some combinations, but I need all the combinations, also in order to control if I've done correctly what I've done.

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: What goes wrong when you apply the standard methods to the case of a biased coin?

Comment: One thing you might try: if you have some analytical solution, and you'd like to check it, construct a Monte Carlo simulation and make your own victory matrix. It's a fun (to me, at least) coding exercise! Of course, this requires you to have just a little bit of coding skill already.

Comment: For example I found these probabilities:
HHH VS HHT     1-p
HHH VS HTH      p/(1+p-p^2)
HHH VS HTT       (1-2p+p^2)/(1-2p+3p^2-p^3)
HHH VS TTT        1-p
HTH VS HTT        1-p

I'm still working on other combinations, but, for example, I didn't manage to find HHH VS TTH

Comment: I also found HHH VS THT      (-p^4+3p^3-2p^2-p+1)/(1-p+p^2)

Comment: Actually I managed to find any combination and also check them, except for HHH VS TTH and HHT VS TTT, I can't find a strategy

Comment: Cross-posted on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/416621.